# Como eu posso criar atualizar função no colab sem precisar restartar o kernel dele?

Tags: python, funções, google, ipython-notebook, kernel

Eu tenho minhas funções feitas fora do colab, em arquivos py, porém eu gostaria de alterar a função e não precisar restartar o kernel do colab. Para que essa função funcione no notebook  eu nesse momento estou precisando restartar todo o notebook, eu gostaria de passar algum parâmetro ou algo do gênero para que eu possa rodar a função, editar novamente e conseguir utilizar ela no estado atual dele.

Answer (score 2):

A função "reload" da importlib pode forçar o modulo  a ser re-executado, e aí o processo Python do seu Kernel vai ter a nova função.

O problema é que `importlib.reload` sozinho sempre funciona para o módulo (no caso, seus arquivos .py) e não para a função sozinha -

Então, se você tem um arquivo "meuarquivo.py" e lá dentro "def minhafuncao(): ...",
precisa fazer essas duas coisas - eu recomendo deixar uma célula de rascunho próxima do ponto onde você está trabalhando com isso, e re-executar esta célula cada vez que alterar a função:

```
import meuarquivo  # só é necessário se "meuarquivo" não foi importado antes

from importlib import reload

reload(meuarquivo)

minhafuncao = meuarquivo.minhafuncao
```

Em vez da última linha, pode usar a sintaxe de import também, (mas
depois de executar o `reload`):  `from meuarquivo import minhafuncao`.

Se tiver mais de uma função ou constantes definidas no arquivo, o assignent
no notebook tem que ser feito para cada elemento que você usar, individualmente.
Por exemplo:  `from meuarquivo import funcao1, funcao2, df_horarios`

E por fim, se não quiser fazer o reassignment, pode também sempre usar o nome por extenso (qualified name) de tudo o que estiver no arquivo que você for atualizar.
Assim, se em todos os pontos em que você usa a função no notebook sempre usar `meuarquivo.minhafuncao` em vez de usar o `from meuarquivo import funcao`, só precisa mesmo fazer a chamada ao reload.

Answer (score 1):

`importlib` é uma ótima opção, pois ela realmente atualiza a função podendo depois ser utilizada posteriormente, depois de importar sua função pode utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(suaFuncao)
```

Comment: O caso de uso informado na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) não é o de recarga de funções e sim recarga de módulos.